# Stitching Histograms using Popmon - Value Error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram, monitoring, population

I use the popmon library to generate and stitch histograms.

I try to extract 2 histograms from 2 different datasets then stitch them together.
While I try to do that, I get this error:

**ValueError: Input histograms are not all similar**

```
features = ["datetime:prog_revenue"]
may10_hists = may10_df.pm_make_histograms(
    features=features, time_axis="datetime", time_width="1h", time_offset="2023-05-10"
)
may9_hists = may9_df.pm_make_histograms(
    features=features, time_axis="datetime", time_width="1h", time_offset="2023-05-09"
)

hist_add = popmon.stitch_histograms(
    hists_basis=may9_hists, hists_delta=may10_hists, mode="add"
)
```

Before I encounter this error, I also get this warning at the stitching step.

> Input SparselyBin histograms have inconsistent origin attributes:
> [1.6835904e+18, 1.6836768e+18]

Can someone help me resolve this issue? I am clueless about the next resolution step for this issue.